# Apache Cassandra JDBC connection error

Tags: database, jdbc, nosql, cassandra, cassandra-jdbc

I want to connect to cassandra 1.2.4 on a remote server through jdbc.

```
 package cassandraclient;
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;

 public class CassClient {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {

         Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");

         Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://<domain>:7199");

        String query = "CREATE KEYSPACE CassandraClientTest WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };";
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();

        boolean success = statement.execute(query);
        System.out.println("created keyspace " + success);
        statement.close();

        con.close();

    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 }
```

When I try to establish a connection I get the following exception.

```
    java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.<init>(CassandraConnection.java:156)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:92)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at cassandraclient.CassClient.main(CassClient.java:17)
    Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.readFrame(TFramedTransport.java:129)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.read(TFramedTransport.java:101)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:378)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:297)
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:204)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_describe_cluster_name(Cassandra.java:1101)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.describe_cluster_name(Cassandra.java:1089)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.<init>(CassandraConnection.java:125)
        ... 4 more
```

Also there is something else I noticed. the standard port for cassandra is 9160 and I did not specify another port. But when I try to start cassandra again it gives me the following exception.

```
    Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
            java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

That's why I used port 7199.
when I use port 9160 (and other port like 9161..2) in the url I get this exception.

```
    java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.<init>(CassandraConnection.java:156)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:92)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at cassandraclient.CassClient.main(CassClient.java:28)
    Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraConnection.<init>(CassandraConnection.java:123)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
        ... 5 more
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: boss try with datastax-java driver client. You won't get much support with JDBC

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things are happening here.

The easiest problem to address:

> java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199;
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use

Although C* uses port 9160 for thrift, it also uses port 7199 for JMX. The exception basically means that something else is stopping C* from using that port, my money is on another cassandra server.

Use the activity monitor / tast manager to make sure you have stopped all cassandra instances and then try restarting the server, and if on osx/linux use the -f flag to start the server in the forground, this makes it easier to stop!

```
  Windows> cassandra.bat
OSX/Linux$ ./cassandra -f
```

The next problem (I'm not sure if this is a problem or you just decided to obfuscate the connection string)

```
Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://<domain>:7199");
```

This isn't correct, you need to specify an IP address in the `<domain>` part. E.g:

```
Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://127.0.0.1:9160");
Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://mycassndrahost:9160");
```

Also you cant use port 7199, its needed by JMX and has to be free unless you change the config in your  **cassandra-env.sh** file.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes i decided to obfuscate the connection string. I will try to restart the server and tell you if it fixed my problem.

Comment: sadly restarting the server did not fix my problem

Comment: it sounds like there is another C* server running in the background. Start the activity monitor / task manager and try to find the process and kill it and after try restarting your server.

Comment: thats what i did. I killed the running cassandra instance and started a new one. the problem that persists is the exception when connecting: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connec